# Can I print to PDF with my iPad?

Tags: ipad, pdf, printing

The missing print to PDF feature on iPad (like that of Mac OS X) has been written about in a couple places on the web, but they all reference iPad apps that are no longer present in the App Store.

Is there a way to get PDF generation in the iPad print dialog?

Has Apple decided to pull such products from the App Store?

Comment: Yes, you can now do this. See my answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263121/7244)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "print" a web page to a PDF in Safari on iOS (iPad)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114285/how-to-print-a-web-page-to-a-pdf-in-safari-on-ios-ipad)

Answer (score 1):

On iPadOS 15 and other recent releases, taking a screen shot of Safari lets you capture the entire page as PDF. All apps can now share and print to PDF out of the box and only very specific apps that intentionally try to disable sharing can’t print these days. What a welcome change for iPad and iPadOS.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205751

The mark up tools are excellent and I find iPad so much better for this than even Windows 10 and macOS with Acrobat Pro installed.

---

Those products didn't currently (and don't today) follow the accepted API that Apple provides for apps submitted to the App Store. Basically, Apple provides the print code and apps can't modify or extend the print function that iOS provides.

Until this changes, you will be bound to workarounds:

1. Jailbreak the device and look for something that enables this function.
2. Print to a device that will render the job as PDF. I know of [Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/) that will do explicitly this. You can even control which folder on the mac gets the PDF and have it uploaded back to the phone or to a private cloud so you can get at the PDF again systematically from iOS.
3. Use apps that can save to PDF like [Pages](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8) and many others, but this is an app feature, not built into the main print settings.

Comment: This answer may have been useful at some point but should probably only be a last resort nowadays. There is a linked question with more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks you for the constructive criticism @KayV I have made an edit to explain how much better things are now. Should I add this link as well to my answer? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205751

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "Print n Share Pro" for document, web page and email conversion to PDF. It has its own full email and web browser so doesn't need AirPrint. It also supports "Open in" from other apps and cloud servers. [Product page](http://mobile.eurosmartz.com/products/printnsharepro.html) or [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/print-n-share-pro/id471352087?mt=8)
It saved my bacon when I had to submit a load of emails in PDF format for a customer support presentation.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the OP question, which was about "PDF generation in the iPad print dialog".